# Can we try not to autolink URLs to reserved internal pages?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

When people asking questions about web applications, they can describe the result of their actions as e.g.

> I load http://127.0.0.1/ in my browser. I click the button. I expect to be sent to http://127.0.0.1/Page1, but I'm sent to http://127.0.0.1/Page2 instead.

There's no benefit here in making the links clickable, it happens automatically, and there is no easy way to prevent it. It's understandable that users don't manage to prevent it.

This then prompts comments that attempt to educate the asker on their internal links not being accessible to the readers. It's equally understandable that users don't notice that the asker didn't specifically set out to make the links clickable.

Can SE detect when the host portion of an automatically detected URL is an unqualified domain name or an IP address in one of the reserved ranges, and if so, leave it as plain text instead? In the rare case that someone actually *wants* to create an internal link (in the style of "click this link to see if you're vulnerable"), that's still easy enough to do with an explicit link, Markdown or HTML style.

Comment: Just edit the post (or suggest an edit) replacing the link with `http://example.com/Page1`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure if you're suggesting changing the host to example.com to make it clearer that it's intentional, or if you're suggesting marking the URLs as code so that they don't get autolinked. If the former, then yeah, I suppose it will reduce the problem; it still doesn't make sense for the links to be clickable, but at least it'll be clearer that they're not meant to work. If the latter, please don't, they aren't code, and random non-code being displayed as code is a real problem that is making questions and answers unreadable.

Comment: Your post doesn't appear to include any code, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: On SO there are [2315](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%22) posts with the 127.0.0.1 address. It is only a usability issue, right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey You used code markup for the URL in your comment. That's what I was referring to. Is that something you were suggesting doing?

Comment: No, I just included the ticks because, if you don't, it looks like this in a comment: http://example.com  ... I suppose I could have used `[http://example.com](http://example.com)`, which would have yielded [http://example.com](http://example.com).

Comment: @rene And 1586 posts with 192., and 622 with 10., and 24004 posts with localhost. I'm not sure if I missed anything. I do not know exactly what qualifies or doesn't qualify as a usability issue, so I do not know if it's only a usability issue.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Okay, so you're not suggesting using code markup to prevent autolinking, but you're using code markup to prevent autolinking. :) More seriously, thanks for clarifying, while I don't think using example.com is ideal, I do think it's an improvement and a good enough workaround.

Comment: RFC 2606 specifies that example.com is reserved for testing and documentation purposes. If that's not ideal, what is?

Comment: @DavidZ The fact that it'll still be presented as a link and lead to an error if a reader clicks it, when no one tried to make it clickable in the first place, is not ideal.

Comment: @DavidZ: It's ideal but you'll _never_ train everyone to abide by such an abstraction.